# How to connect my listview example item to next page

Tags: android

i'm new to Android Programming. I was developing a small project using ListView which shows 5 subjects on the first screen. Selecting any particular subject should open a new respective subject's page. I have already written the java code that only adds the 5 subject, thats it! 
I have no further clue as to what to do. Please Help!!

Comment: Just activiy_main with 5 subjects as list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay do this in your that activity which shows 5 subjects in list.

```
ArrayList<String> subjects = new ArrayList<String>();

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.ur_xml);


    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list); // list in your XML

    subjects.add("Maths");
    subjects.add("English");
    subjects.add("Computer");
    subjects.add("Biology");
    subjects.add("XYZ");


ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
            ur_present_class.this,
            android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1, subjects);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            switch (position) {

            case 0:
                Intent i = new Intent(present_class.this,
                        Math.class);
                startActivity(i);
                break;
case 1:
                Intent i1 = new Intent(present_class.this,
                        English.class);
                startActivity(i1);
                break;
case 2:
                Intent i2 = new Intent(present_class.this,
                        Computer.class);
                startActivity(i2);
                break;
case 3:
                Intent i3 = new Intent(present_class.this,
                        Biology.class);
                startActivity(i3);
                break;
case 4:
                Intent i4 = new Intent(present_class.this,
                        XYZ.class);
                startActivity(i4);
                break;
});
}
```

Comment: and what should i write in my main_activity. java to make the transfer take place ?

Comment: very sorry i just came online right now so answering you , just write all these things in your main it will take to your desired activity (class , of your required subject) make sure all of your activities are declared in manifest.xml

Comment: Could you please elaborate. Sorry for the trouble

Comment: look , make five separate classes for respective subjects and put info in there by making 5 separate xml fives for each respectively, ok.
then put selected above code in your main activity , then before running go to manifest.xml then add <activity name="ur_package_name.class_name"/> for all five added classes then run your program.

Answer (score 1):

write

```
    YourListView.setOnItemclickListner(new OnItemCLickListner)
```

and inside the onclick()
write an intent to next activity you want to go

check this out for more about intents

[Intent dev](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html)

```
   Intent intent = new Intent(yourActivityName.this,ActivityYouwantToGo.class);
   startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: is "ActivityYouwantToGo" an .xml file defined under /res folder ??
sorry i'm completely new so i dont know anything properly yet.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an OnItemClickListener to your list which will start a new activity.

Can you post your code.

Comment: String[] subject = new String[] { "OOMD", "SSM", "TEA-II", "SCM","WEB 2.0"}; 
        ArrayList<String> subjectList = new ArrayList<String>();
        subjectList.addAll( Arrays.asList(subject) );
        listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.simplerow, subjectList);
       
        mainListView.setAdapter( listAdapter );

Answer (score 0):

First you should check how Android ListActivity works [Here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html) . Then you should check this [link](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/) who explain how you can customise your ListView with [BaseAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html) . If you follow the link you should have a cool ListView at the end.

Next if you want something happen when you clik on item, supposing your activity extend ListActivity you can Override

```
   @Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

    Intent intent = new Intent(this.getActivity(), ActivityYouWantOpen.class);
    intent.putExtra("something", list.get(position).getSomething()); //if you want to save specific info of the clicked item
    startActivity(intent);
}
```